# PC not coming out of hibernate mode

Tags: power, hibernate

I leave the PC for few hours and my PC ran into hibernate mode. Now after turning on the PC monitor displays nothing but **check signal cable**. I have turned off the main supply and unplug the power cable but PC is still in hibernate mode. Tried to restart because once it worked for me but this time nothing happens when I restart the PC.

I don't understand what should I do to get it out from hibernate. Please help me out

Comment: `I have turned off the main supply and unplug the power cable but PC is still in hibernate mode.` Are you sure it's not a power supply problem?

Comment: Yes I am sure. PC has stuck in hibernate mode.

Comment: The PC cannot be "stuck" in hibernation if you take the power out completely. Hibernation is basically a shutdown but it keeps the contents in RAM to a hard drive. So if your computer cannot turn on again, there's definitely something wrong with either the motherboard or the power supply.

Comment: It sounds like a computer is not turning on, which would be explained by a power supply problem, a machine cannot be "stuck in hibernate" mode since your machine is turned off currently.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't confusing "sleep" with "hibernate"?  They are very different.  See @KingDuken explanation.  Yes, the word you are using matters.

Comment: @KingDuken, in *Hibernation*, *all* RAM is written to disk. No power is used after that. In *Sleep* (or standby) mode, there is a trickle of power required to keep RAM refreshed and CPU alive enough to respond to wake-up signals.

Answer (score 0):

The message on the display, "Check **signal cable**", implies the cable has become unplugged. The message could also be due a fault in the cable, monitor or video card. Investigate the issue in order of convenience:

- Check the display. Turn it off or unplug it, then turn it on.
- Check the video cable. Reseat connectors. Try another cable.
- Move the display to another PC to confirm it works.
- Try another display on the PC.
- Reseat the video card.
- Try another video card.

Answer (score 0):

Comments that "PC can't be stuck in hibernate mode because it's off" are wrong. It's true that a hibernated computer is powered off completely, but [it's in a different ACPI power state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface#Global_states): hibernation is S4 and soft-off (a regular shutdown) is S5. From user's perspective there's no difference, but it can (should?) be implemented differently.

I've seen a computer that had the same problem as you're describing. I didn't have an opportunity to diagnose the problem, though, but in that case resetting BIOS temporarily resolved the issue and restored full functionality. It's done by shorting specific two specific pins on the motherboard for some time. Check your motherboard's manual for exact instructions.